# Undefined variable: st_textdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, undefined

I am quite new to coding and going into the depths of php is always an overwhelming experience for me, so I would really appreciate your help.

I am running a website on wordpress.org and suddenly two undefined variables appeared in my blog section just where the author and post date are.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: st_textdomain in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/wunderkind/content-image.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined variable: st_textdomain in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/wunderkind/content-image.php on line 17
```

Now the code looks like this:

```
    <p itemprop="author"><?php _e('by',$st_textdomain)?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>"><?php the_author() ?></a>
        <small><?php echo get_user_meta(get_the_author_meta('ID'),'job',true) ?></small></p>

    <p itemprop="datePublished"><span class="icon ion-ios7-clock"></span> <?php echo __('Posted on',$st_textdomain)?> <?php echo the_date('F d, Y \a\t H:i A') ?></p>
   <?php>}
```

I was just wondering if this will fix it

```
    <?php if(!empty($st_textdomain)) { ?>
    <p itemprop="author"><?php _e('by',$st_textdomain)?> <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>"><?php the_author() ?></a> <small><?php echo get_user_meta(get_the_author_meta('ID'),'job',true) ?></small></p>

    <p itemprop="datePublished"><span class="icon ion-ios7-clock"></span> <?php echo __('Posted on',$st_textdomain)?> <?php echo the_date('F d, Y \a\t H:i A') ?></p>

    <?php } ?>
```

Thank you again for your time.

Comment: change !empty to isset and try not mix php and html

Comment: I am a bit embarassed but extremely grateful. It did the job, even though with the notice the author and date of the posts have disappered as well, but it's something that I actually don't mind. 

Thank you!